# How hide script field from new MonoBehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm want to hide script field from new scripts. (script are shown by default by every script)

[image]

One way is writing `CustomEditor` for our script.

but i want faster way do that. without writing editor script for my new script.

Comment: Honestly, I have no clue what you're trying to say. If you add pictures to show what you're hiding this post might make a _little_ more sense.

Comment: Huh? You want to do what now? Your question is confusing. Also, how does `private` not solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that create new attribute for more control.

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class HideScriptField : Attribute { }
```

And as editor script for all script that has this new attribute

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(MonoBehaviour), true)]
public class DefaultMonoBehaviourEditor : Editor
{
    private bool hideScriptField;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        hideScriptField = target.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HideScriptField), false).Length > 0;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        if (hideScriptField)
        {
            serializedObject.Update();
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            DrawPropertiesExcluding(serializedObject, "m_Script");
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
                serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnInspectorGUI();
        }
    }
}
```

Now in every new `MonoBehaviour` script if you want to hide script field you can add simply this attribute (`HideScriptField`) on it. and done.

Comment: Did you just answer your own question in the very moment you ask it?

Comment: Not unheard of, but I'm confused as to why it was done in this case. It's not like it even really adds anything to the site.

Comment: @Vulpex You can ask and answer your own question at the-same time as long as it's not a duplicate and can be useful to others. Although it looks like people hate it.

Comment: It would be good if you explain what you did in your answer instead of just posting code.

Comment: Stop shaming people for sharing knowledge

Answer (score -2):

From what I understand from your extremely poorly worded question I managed to conclude that you need [attributes](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Attributes.html)

```
[SerializeField]
private CustomClass x;
```

is a private field that is shown in inspector.

```
[HideInInspector]
public CustomClass x;
```

is a public field that is not visible in inspector.